# Tracking logon sessions in Office365 logs

Tags: logging, microsoft-office-365, session

I am investigating data in O365 logs. Is there a way to distinguish which session a certain activity belonged? for example, if a user has his mobile phone, home PC and work PC logged on, how can I tell which device did the action?

Answer (score 1):

Taken from: [Use Office 365 tools for security investigations in Exchange Online and SharePoint Online](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt219044.aspx)

**To examine the devices and applications from which a specific user connected to a mailbox in Office 365**

1. In the Security & Compliance Center, choose **Reports > View reports**.
2. Under **Auditing**, choose **Azure AD reports**.
3. In the Azure management portal, on the **Active Directory tab**, choose the name of your organization.
4. Under your organization name, choose **Users**.
5. Locate the user you want to investigate and choose the username.
6. On the user page, choose Devices.
7. In the **View** drop-down list, select **Devices and applications from which the user has signed in**. This will provide details, such as the version of client used to sign in, and the last sign-in time, IP address, and location of the user.